# Use hand row operation to find inverse

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$$\begin{cases}
2x+4y=-8\\
4x-6y=-2
\end{cases}$$

I'm having trouble with hand row operations. Trying to teach myself. Could anyone help? Sorry for the bad format, I'm on my phone

Comment: "to find *inverse*"?  What inverse are you looking for?  Are you trying to find a *solution* to the above system of equations?

Comment: To solve this system (meaning: to find every pair $(x,y)$ such that both equations hold) use the three elementary row operations: switching two rows, multiplying a row by a nonzero constant, and adding a multiple of one row to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the system $$\begin{cases}
2x+4y=-8\\
4x-6y=-2
\end{cases} \iff \pmatrix{2 & 4 \\ 4 & -6}\pmatrix{x \\ y}=\pmatrix{-8 \\ -2}$$

I'm going to assume you want to solve this system by **finding the inverse** of the matrix $\pmatrix{2 & 4 \\ 4 & -6}$.  That's doable.

There are formulas for the inverse matrices for $n\times n$ matrices for different sizes but let's just go through the most basic way of finding the inverse matrix:  Gaussian elimination.

The idea here is to set of a block matrix of the form $\left[A\mid I\right]$ where $A$ is your matrix and $I$ is the identity matrix.  Then perform elementary row operations until you get this augmented matrix into the form $\left[I\mid B\right]$.  If you're successful (not every square matrix is invertible) then $B$ will be the inverse of $A$.  So let's try it:

$$\begin{align}\left(\begin{array}{cc|cc} 2 & 4 & 1 & 0 \\ 4 & -6 &  0 & 1\end{array}\right) &\longrightarrow \left(\begin{array}{cc|cc} 2 & 4 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -14 &  -2 & 1\end{array}\right) &\left(R_2\to R_2-2R_1\right)\\ &\longrightarrow \left(\begin{array}{cc|cc} 2 & 4 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & \frac 17 & -\frac 1{14}\end{array}\right) &\left(R_2 \to -\frac 1{14}R_2\right)\\ &\longrightarrow \left(\begin{array}{cc|cc} 2 & 0 & \frac 37 & \frac 27 \\ 0 & 1 & \frac 17 & -\frac 1{14} \end{array}\right) &\left(R_1\to R_1-4R_2\right)\\ &\longrightarrow \left(\begin{array}{cc|cc} 1 & 0 & \frac 3{14} & \frac 17 \\ 0 & 1 & \frac 17 & -\frac 1{14} \end{array}\right) &\left(R_1\to \frac{1}{2}R_1\right)\end{align}$$

Thus $\frac 1{14}\pmatrix{3 & 2 \\ 2 & -1}$ should be the inverse matrix.  Now just multiply both sides of your original matrix equation by this inverse matrix to get $$\pmatrix{x \\ y} = \frac 1{14}\pmatrix{3 & 2 \\ 2 & -1}\pmatrix{-8 \\ -2} = \pmatrix{-2 \\ -1}$$

Then if you plug in this pair $(x,y)$ into the original equation you'll find we (I) didn't make any mistakes.  Yay!

Comment: Thanks a lot, btw cowboy bebop rules. :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to solve the system to find a solution for $x$ and $y$.  You have multiple options on how to proceed.

One of the simplest to learn is the method of *substitution*.

$\begin{cases}2x+4y=-8\\4x-6y=-2\end{cases}$

Move the $4y$ to the other side of the first equation.

$\begin{cases}2x=-8-4y\\4x-6y=-2\end{cases}$

Divide both equations by two.

$\begin{cases}x=-4-2y\\2x-3y=-1\end{cases}$

The first equation tells you what $x$ is equal to in terms of $y$ and constants.  Use this information in the second equation.

$\begin{cases}x=-4-2y\\ 2(-4-2y)-3y=-1\end{cases}$

Now, the second equation is only in terms of $y$ and can be simplified using elementary methods.

---

Another method to learn is the method of *elimination*.  Try to combine the equations in such a way that you completely remove one of the variables.

$\begin{cases}2x+4y=-8\\4x-6y=-2\end{cases}$

Taking twice the first equation and subtracting the second equation, you are left with:

$\begin{cases}2x+4y=-8\\14y=-14\end{cases}$

---

In either method, you will learn a value for $y$.  Using this value for $y$, you can then use that information to learn what $x$ is.

---

Both methods are generalized and can be expressed using matrices and the process known as [Gaussian Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).

Following the algorithm described in the link exactly, we first describe our system using an augmented matrix:

$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}2&4&-8\\4&-6&-2\end{array}\right]$

First, I make sure the top left entry is nonzero by swapping rows if necessary.  (Already done).  Next I make it the top left entry a one by multiplying (equivalently dividing) by an appropriate number.  In this case, I divide by $2$.

$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}1&2&-4\\4&-6&-2\end{array}\right]$

Next, I want to clear out all other entries in the first column.  (exactly the same as elimination normally).  I do so by subtracting four times the first row away from the second row.

$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}1&2&-4\\0&-14&14\end{array}\right]$

I continue the process by shifting my focus down and over, now looking at the second row second column entry and trying to make that a one and clearing out the rest of its column until I arrive at something looking like this:

$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}1&0&*\\0&1&**\end{array}\right]$

This can then be reinterpreted as your system of equations reading $x=*$ and $y=**$

Comment: I understand how to do elimination and substitution but hand row operations is another way to find the same solution.

Comment: @user281641 "Hand row operations" is exactly the same as elimination and substitution, just given a different flavor.